# GPL - Is it required to post source code to the Public - when is a software released?

Tags: gpl, source-code, release

The GPL FAQ  ["Does the GPL require that source code of modified versions be posted to the public?"](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLRequireSourcePostedPublic) contains this statement (**emphasis** by me):

> The GPL does not require you to release your modified version,
> or any part of it. You are free to make modifications and use them
> privately, without ever releasing them. This applies to organizations
> (including companies), too; an organization can make a modified
> version and use it internally without ever releasing it outside the
> organization.
>
> **But if you release the modified version to the public in some way**,
> the GPL requires you to make the modified source code available to the
> program's users, under the GPL.
>
> Thus, the GPL gives permission to release the modified program in
> certain ways, and not in other ways; but the decision of whether to
> release it is up to you.

My question is, when is the condition `release to the public` met / fulfilled?

Let us assume that a website is using a modified PHP-CMS that is licensed under the gpl. Is the fact, that the website which can be reached over the internet already enough to speak of a release of the server side software?

What if only logged in users can use the CMS?

Comment: The GPLv3 has clarified matters a bit by introducing the term *conveying* instead of *releasing* or *publishing*. The license allows conveying as something that enables others to make or receive a copy of the software. Mere interaction with a program is not conveying.

Comment: Also note that it does not state *when* or *how* to make the modified source code available. IMHO, in many cases it happens upon request of a user only. This may go unnoticed for years.

Comment: I once heard somewhere that it is sufficient to print the code on paper to fullfill the requirement to provide the code. Is that the case?

Comment: @surfmuggle That would make a decent new question; please feel free to make a new post to ask it!

Comment: You're not required to distribute the source to anyone *except* people you've distributed the software to. i.e. If you hand someone a copy of the program, you're required to offer them the source code, if you make it available via a website, you're required to offer the source to the people who downloaded it. You can do this by distributing it only in source form, by including the source with the binaries, by including a link with the binaries to where the source can be downloaded, by giving them your contact info, then giving them the source (by whatever means) when they request it, etc.

Comment: @ThomasWeller conveying of source code should be in a similar manner as the conveying of object code (executable). If I down-load a program, then requiring be to send a stamp addressed envelope, and a fee for a CD, or the source-code, is unreasonable. But if this is how I got the executable, then it is reasonable.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor is this phrasing `conveying of source code should be in a similar manner as the conveying of object code` your point of view or a requirement that is part of the gpl?

Comment: @surmuggle GPL2 in section 3: GPL 2 is very vague ”on a medium customarily used for software interchange”. It is more clear in GPL3 section 6: “…d) Convey the object code by offering access from a designated place (gratis or for a charge), and offer equivalent access to the Corresponding Source in the same way through the same place at no further charge.…”

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is the fact, that the website which can be reached over the internet already enough to speak of a release of the server side software?

No, it isn't, which is why the [Affero GPL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl.html) was developed.  The AGPL extends the group of people who are entitled to have the source to include people who interact with the software over a network (see s13).

If the PHP code of this CMS is given or sold to some third-party, for example so that they can create their own website, that counts as conveyance under the regular (non-Affero) GPL (as well as under the AGPL).

> What if only logged in users can use the cms?

I don't yet know of any jurisprudence or qualified advice as to what constitutes *interaction remotely through a computer network*.  It seems clear to me that a logged-in user is interacting with it.  Whether someone who enters an invalid username/password and thus fails to log in is interacting with it is an interesting question, and I don't think there's a definitive answer to it yet.  My personal feeling is that it would include such non-users, but it's just my opinion.

Comment: I imagine you might be able to circumvent the "non-logged in user" problem by doing logins via a separate reverse proxy which is not AGPL'd - which may be desirable for reasons unrelated to copyright, see for example the [BeyondCorp model](https://cloud.google.com/beyondcorp/). Of course, Google doesn't use AGPL'd software in the first place, so YMMV on the legal technicalities of doing this.